# I want to reduce the running time of OpenCV grabCut in AWS Lambda

Tags: opencv, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have tested openCV grabCut in Lambda.
This is grabcut test source.

```
        // get a native file from jar and write to /tmp/. It's duration 1 sec.
        getFileFromResource(context.getLogger(), nativeFile); 
        System.load("/tmp/libopencv_java2411.so");

        Rect rect = new Rect(120, 275, 660, 240);
        Mat image = Highgui.imread("/tmp/sample.jpg");
        Mat mask = Mat.zeros(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
        Mat bgdModel = new Mat();
        Mat fgdModel = new Mat();

        if (image == null || image.empty()) {
            logger.log("Failed to read image");
            return new Response("fail to read image");
        }

        // grabcut 
        Imgproc.grabCut( image, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 1, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT );

        // make foreground mask
        Mat binMask = Mat.zeros( mask.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1 );
        Core.compare(mask, new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_FGD), binMask, Core.CMP_EQ);
        Core.compare(mask, new Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD), binMask, Core.CMP_EQ);

        // save image
        Highgui.imwrite("/tmp/output.jpg", binMask);

        binMask.release();
        image.release();
        mask.release();
        bgdModel.release();
        fgdModel.release();
```

- When the memory type is 1536MB, the running duration is 4.7s.
- When the momory type is 1024MB, the running duration is 6.8s.
- This is an average value after executing 10 times.

The running duration is a little slow. The running duration is about 2.1s in local PC. 
Of course, I know the Max memory setting value is 1536MB, and can't increase this yet.

Is there any good idea to reduce the execution time?

Comment: As you have already reduced the `iterations` in grabcut to `1`, so another possible way is to resize the original image, the image size is directly proportional to the time taken in grabcut.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Today, when i tested downsized image, the running duration was about 1 sec. (This is an average value after executing 10 times.)

Comment: Hi how did you manage to make opencv run on lambda? Did you upload a static version?

Comment: @RomanzoCriminale perhaps something similar to https://markn.ca/2015/10/python-extension-modules-in-aws-lambda/ but that could be asked as a new question.

Comment: @RomanzoCriminale Python execution speed is faster than Java (case openCV). So lambda has been uploaded on to tie the python executable package.